# How to get record by Id without recordType in netsuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I could get record by below code

```
record.load(recordType, id)
```

For above function, both args are required.

Any way to get record by id alone without recordType in netsuite suitescript 2.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not possible, you do have to get the recordType but in case your records are transactions such as: Sales Orders, Purchase Orders, Invoices, etc.

You can use the following code to get the recordType only having the id:

```
                    var recordType = search.lookupFields({
                         type: search.Type.TRANSACTION,
                         id: your_record_id,
                         columns: 'type'
                    });
```

then you can use the record.load for your needs.

Comment: Seconding that it is not possible. Internal IDs are not globally unique in NetSuite. Both a Customer and a Sales Order might have the Internal ID `1`; so you have to specify a record type when loading a record.